# How to set noclobber option without it logging to the console that it has been set?

Tags: bash

I enabled the noclobber option in my bashrc to prevent overwriting files on stdout. I really like this feature, but I dislike that anytime I open a new terminal window or source my bashrc, it prints out "clobber off" to the terminal.

Like this (refresh is alias for source '~/.bashrc'):

```
dan:[~/.../frontend/cv-project](main↑1|1U 5M)$ refresh
noclobber       off
```

This is how I set noclobber in my .bashrc:

```sh
# Prevent overwriting file on stdout redirection
# Use `>|` to force redirection to an existing file
shopt -o noclobber
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `-q` flag like this:

```bash
shopt -qo noclobber
```

For more info about shopt see: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html

Answer (score 1):

Since `noclobber` is actually a `set` setting, use `set` instead of `shopt`

```sh
set -o noclobber
# or
set -C
```

Refs:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin
- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin

Answer (score 0):

Just redirect the stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`.

```
shopt -o noclobber &> /dev/null
```